# How to give specific color in specific area?

Tags: color

As shown below, the yellow color appears only on both edges, I have tried vertex color for the yellow, but I can't give another color in node editor.

Is it possible to give specific color on specific area?

[image: how do i make my edges look like pic ref]

Comment: Did you try to use a texture?

Comment: In the reference image, all the colours are blended with each other so I think that you will need to texture paint your model.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign any one material to a face at a time. However, you can apply a uv image to the object. This will allow you to paint freely on the object in as much detail as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

To assign colors you want to see in the rendering you should add them to the material.

You can assign different materials to different faces (but I would not recommend it in this case, cause you'd need to many faces), or use UV-mapping as shown below:

1. If you have an image with the map of the colors you want to apply to the object you can load it in the UV Image Editor, if not you should create it.
2. Then you need to unwrap (search on YouTube for tutorials about it; you'll find a lot of tips to do it) the faces.
3. Position/rotate/scale the unwrapped faces in the UV Image Editor (you'll see them if you are in edit mode and have all the geometry selected.
4. Use nodes to apply the (UV map as a texture for the object's material).

Look at [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ck_DCf21KMM) if you need help with unwrapping/texturing.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe someone coming here years later will actually find use to this answer as no one actually answered this question in a way for a new person to blender can understand.

- In object mode select the object you want to color.
- Click on 'Material Properties' in your tab menu.
- Click plus sign to add new material (this is just a base material don't add color.
- Click the New button to add the material to the list of materials for this object.
  ---click assign
- Click tab to go into edit mode.
- Select the faces you want to specifically color.
- Under material properties click the plus sign again
- Click the new button again
- Pick whatever color you want to add to the object under base color.
  ---click assign

Comment: If you think of a new user who doesn't know about using different materials, then I doubt this is helpful. Let's assume that someone creates a _UV Sphere_. The sphere comes with a default material in the first material slot. Now if he follows your instructions, he starts by adding a second material to it in _Object Mode_, then he selects some faces in _Edit Mode_ and creates a third material where he changes the color to let's say blue and that's it... now he has a white sphere (default material) with two extra  materials white and blue on it which are not in use...

Comment: I see you edited your answer after my comment... but now you first tell to 'click assign' after adding a material in _Object Mode_, but that's not possible because the _Assign_ button only shows up in _Edit Mode_. It is also unnecessary to say "this is just a base material don't add color" because a base material can of course be colored, too - why should it be white? I can see no value in your answer, one could only learn how to add two materials and maybe add a color to some faces. I would rather suggest to watch a beginner tutorial on materials and then it's minimum basics you can learn.